# Странное поведение Balloon с задержкой открытия в api яндекс карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

У меня есть objectManager, я в него гружу объекты.

Хотел сделать красивую анимацию:  при клике на метке карта плавно двигается к ней, масштабируется и затем у неё открывается балун. Сразу открывать некрасиво - открытие балуна само анимируется, что отменяет другие анимации, плюс балун сам масштабируется при зуме, а только после приобретает нормальный размер.

Вроде всё просто.

```
objectManager.objects.options.set(
      {
       ..., 
       openBalloonOnClick:true,   
       balloonMaxWidth: 260,
       balloonOpenTimeout:1800
});

objectManager.objects.events.add("click", function (event) {  
myMap.setCenter(coord,myMap.getZoom(),{duration:1000});
setTimeout(function(){myMap.setZoom(19,{duration:500});},1600); });
```

Однако, в данном случае балун почему-то открывается в нулевых глобальных пиксельных координатах (вблизи северного полюса).

Если задан AutoPan:true, то карта отправляется туда, если не задан - просто нет балуна.

Пробовал сам открывать балун по таймауту

```
 objectManager.objects.balloon.open(objectId);
```

Результат тот же.

Функция setPosition вроде как определена, но не отрабатывает.

```
objectManager.objects.balloon.setPosition(coord);
```

Если же я открываю балун без всяких таймаутов (своих или встроенных), то всё работает как надо.

Видимо при таймауте балун теряет координаты объекта, к которому привязан.

При этом id объекта в балун передаётся правильно, содержимое балуна объекту соответствует.

Так что же это, баг такой или я где-то туплю?

И ещё вдогонку вопрос: можно ли как то реализовать, чтобы метки (ну и балун тоже) перерисовывались в процессе зума, а то у меня иконки меток на весь экран становятся пока зум не завершился.

Comment: Без живого стенда сложно понять какая ошибка происходит. Могли бы вы добавить пример на jsfiddle или codepen?

Comment: В том то и дело - ошибка не происходит. Вернее в консоли ошибок всё чисто. Оставлять на сайте такой код не могу.

Comment: В целом проблема решилась использованием setCenter с параметром зума. Ранее все проблемы были в использовании setTimeout(function(){myMap.setZoom(19,{duration:500});},1000); }); То есть, если вызвать ассинхронное изменение зума, терялись координаты балуна. Кстати, почему-то что setCenter, что setZoom работают плавно только при определённой разнице массштабов, если изменение масштаба больше 5 (примерно), зумирование происходит мгновенно. Ответ же на второй вопрос про перерисовку тоже хотелось бы узнать.